# 'xsim' with 'exam' class

Tags: exam, xsim

I am getting error while using xsim package with exam class.

For exaple:
    LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\points' already defined! For immediate help type H . }

How to remove it?

Otherwise I cannot create the different types of questions like multiple choice, fill in the blanks, true-false etc.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[verbose,clear-aux]{xsim}
\usepackage{xsimverb,listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,fmtcount}



\xsimsetup{
    exercise/print = true,
    solution/print = true,
    path=./exercises,
    file-extension = tex,
    exercise/template = bonus,
    grading-table/template = default*
    }

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{xsim package }

\begin{document}
    \begin{exercise}
         A first example for an exercise.
         \end{exercise}
     \begin{solution}
         A first example for a solution.
         \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use both of them? You can do all this with `xsim` alone…

Comment: I am familiar with exam  class where i can create different types of question. Whereas in xsim user manual, i could not find how to set mcq, true-false type questions. One example was there for mcq, but that is incomplete. Blank is also giving error.

Comment: Since they are incompatible, pick one and stick with it.  You might be able to add the missing features.

Comment: `xsim` is heavily extensable but it cannot possibly give examples for every thinkable application. Currently it has 42 example documents listed in the manual some of which describe multiple choice question types.

Comment: What does “Blank is also giving error” mean? As a package author I would very much appreciate a report on the issue tracker if it actually behaves faulty